# Mac: using .profile to customize the command

Tags: linux, macos

I want to customize the command line. (I am new to OS X world and I am trying to figure things out)

I did a `ls -a` and figured out that it does not have `.bashrc` or `.profile`, so I created the `.profile` by myself.

I just wanted to accomplished a simple task, but don't not know how to make it work.

In my `.profile` file, I have one simple line that looks like this

```
export abc = "ssh abc@sometux.com"
```

basically, I can just type `abc` and it connects me to the tux with credential of `abc`. It did not work and when I tried

```
echo abc
```

to debug it, it showed `abc` instead of showing `"ssh abc@sometux.com"` so I guess it did not recognize my profile.

Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: maybe post your question [here](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://apple.stackexchange.com  (AskDifferent) OR http://SuperUser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Thank yo for letting me know. This question is answered by Peder. I will make sure I ask the question in correct site. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You want an alias. This is what you put in .profile:

```
alias abc="ssh abc@sometux.com"
```

Additionally, to list defined aliases, use the command

```
alias
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Do you know what does export do then?

Comment: @FyrZheng [from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720678/what-does-export-path-somethingpath-mean): "`export` sets the environment variable on the left side of the assignment to the value on the right side of the assignment".